# tabularx and pgfplotstableset

Tags: tables, tabularx, pgfplotstable

I would like to make a table in latex similar to this one (extracted from a pdf):

[image]

I have tried with **pgfplotstable** having the values in a csv table:

```
\documentclass[
  english,
  a4paper,
  10pt,
  openany
]{book}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{titlesec} % customize title format
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry} % customize global margings
\usepackage{caption} % customize figure captions
\usepackage{graphicx}% include graphics
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % customize header and footer
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % customize toc
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, tabularx, booktabs} % Generates table from .csv
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl} % use colors for tables
\usepackage{ifpdf} % customize PDF output
\ifpdf
\usepackage[pdftex,
  pagebackref=true,
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  unicode
]{hyperref}
\fi


\begin{document}


\pgfplotstableset{
  debug=true,
  string type,
  header=false,
  col sep=comma,
  row sep=\\,
  every nth row={1}{ before row={\vspace{0.2em}} }, % set space between rows
  every head row/.style={ output empty row },  % suppress printing head row (numbers)
  every row 0 column 0/.style={ postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\cellcolor{white}} }, %suppress first cell (pos 0,0)
  column type/.add={}{ @{\hspace{0.2em}} }, % set space between columns
  columns/0/.style={ column type/.add={>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}}{} },  % first column color
  columns/1/.style={ column type/.add={>{\columncolor[gray]{.95}}}{} }, % second column color
  columns/2/.style={ column type/.add={>{\columncolor[gray]{.95}}}{}  }, % third column color  
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{capabilities.csv} % filename/path to file

\end{document}
```

The result does not respect the paper size (A4), so I have tried to add the **tabularx** modifier to the table with these commands:

```
  begin table={
    \begin{tabularx}{
        \textwidth}{a a a}
  },
  end table={
    \end{tabularx}
  },
```

But it is not compatible (*Undefined control sequence*) with the column modifiers:

```
  column type/.add={}{ @{\hspace{0.2em}} }, % set space between columns
  columns/0/.style={ column type/.add={>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}}{} },  % first column color
  columns/1/.style={ column type/.add={>{\columncolor[gray]{.95}}}{} }, % second column color
  columns/2/.style={ column type/.add={>{\columncolor[gray]{.95}}}{}  }, % third column color
```

I would like to know if there is another method to make the table adjust to the paper size. I am thinking about not using **pgfplotstable**, but I like the idea of having the table data separated from the representation.

NOTE: for a sample, use this *capabilities.csv* table:

```
,Previous Meshlium version,New Meshlium
CPU cores,1,4
CPU architecture,32 bits,64 bits
CPU frequency,500 MHz,1 GHz
RAM,256 MB DDR,2 GB DDR3
Storing,Compact Flash 8 GB,SSD disk 16 GB
Linux Kernel,2.6,3.16
Simultaneous cloud services,2-4,15-20
Boot time,\(\approx\) 2 minutes,Less than 1 minute
WiFi,a/b/g (up to 54 Mbps),a/b/g/n (up to 144 Mbps)
Cellular,Up to 7.2 Mbps downlink (SIM5218) Up to 384 kbps downlink (SIM5215),Up to 42 Mbps downlink
Antenna connectors,4,10
RF module sockets,1,2
Geolocation,GPS,GPS + GLONASS
Root access,Yes,No
Power consumption,\(\approx\) 10 W,\(\approx\) 15 W (depending on number of radios)
Enclosure (mm),210 x 190 x 0, 30 x 220 x 80
Certifications,CE / FCC / IC,CE (Europe) / FCC (US) / IC (Canada) / ANATEL (Brazil) / RCM (Australia) / PTCRB (US) / AT\&T (US)
```

Tnx in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example compilable and provide a sample data input.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have added a full example for compilation with **pdflatex**

Comment: Try `column type=,  
  begin table={\begingroup\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
    >{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}}l
    >{\columncolor[gray]{.95}}X@{\hspace{0.2em}}
    >{\columncolor[gray]{.95}}X}},
  end table={\end{tabularx}\endgroup},`

Comment: Thanks @TeXnician. Despite, it works almost perfect, still I have some problems in the alignement of the interior of the table. It looks like is skyping some part of the text. See [Screenshot.png](https://s17.postimg.org/qux4jm1xr/Screenshot_from_2018-01-08_16_18_52.png)

Comment: Ok, I have found a solution adding \hskip between columns. I will add the solution later. Thanks again

Comment: Still, I can not find a solution for having the header centered as in the example. Is it no other way to have table size adapted to the A4 page?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, following @TeXnician suggestions, this is the code that makes a similar table:

```
\documentclass[
  english,
  a4paper,
  10pt,
  openany
]{book}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{titlesec} % customize title format
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry} % customize global margings
\usepackage{caption} % customize figure captions
\usepackage{graphicx}% include graphics
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % customize header and footer
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % customize toc
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, tabularx, booktabs} % Generates table from .csv
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl} % use colors for tables
\usepackage{ifpdf} % customize PDF output
\ifpdf
\usepackage[pdftex,
  pagebackref=true,
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  unicode
]{hyperref}
\fi



\begin{filecontents*}{matrix.csv}
  ,Previous Meshlium version,New Meshlium
  CPU cores,1,4
  CPU architecture,32 bits,64 bits
  CPU frequency,500 MHz,1 GHz
  RAM,256 MB DDR,2 GB DDR3
  Storing,Compact Flash 8 GB,SSD disk 16 GB
  Linux Kernel,2.6,3.16
  Simultaneous cloud services,2-4,15-20
  Boot time,\(\approx\) 2 minutes,Less than 1 minute
  WiFi,a/b/g (up to 54 Mbps),a/b/g/n (up to 144 Mbps)
  Cellular,Up to 7.2 Mbps downlink (SIM5218) \(\linebreak\)Up to 384 kbps downlink (SIM5215),Up to 42 Mbps downlink
  Antenna connectors,4,10
  RF module sockets,1,2
  Geolocation,GPS,GPS + GLONASS
  Root access,Yes,No
  Power consumption,\(\approx\) 10 W,\(\approx\) 15 W (depending on number of radios)
  Enclosure (mm),210 x 190 x 0, 30 x 220 x 80
  Certifications,CE / FCC / IC,CE (Europe) / FCC (US) / IC (Canada) / ANATEL (Brazil) / RCM (Australia) / PTCRB (US) / AT\&T (US)
\end{filecontents*}



\begin{document}


\pgfplotstableset{zerofill}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  reset styles,
  debug=true,
  string type,
  header=false,
  col sep=comma,
  row sep=newline,
  every first row/.style={
    before row={
      \rowcolor[gray]{0.8} % first row color
      \vspace{0.2em} % first row space between rows
    }
  },
  column type=,
  begin table={
    \begingroup\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
        >{\cellcolor[gray]{.8}}l@{\hskip 1.4em}
        >{\columncolor[gray]{.95}}X@{\hskip 1.4em}
        >{\columncolor[gray]{.95}}X
      }
  },
  end table={\end{tabularx}\endgroup},
  every nth row={1}{ before row={\vspace{0.2em}} }, % set space between rows
  every head row/.style={ output empty row },  % suppress printing head row (numbers)
  every row 0 column 0/.style={ postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\cellcolor{white}} }, %suppress first cell (pos 0,0)    
]{matrix.csv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your code does not compile (anymore?). It gives a `! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the choice 'row sep=crcr' is currently only av
ailable for inline tables, not for external files.` error.

Comment: Thanks @Clément , I have corrected the example. Just change `row setp=\\ `  for `row sep=newline`